# How to get complete path of a directory by giving a subset of its path in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

E.g If I provide `\abc\xyz` , is it possible to get `<drivename>:\somefolder\abc\xyz` ?

Comment: I assume you mean if from a relative path you can get an absolute path ?

Comment: If it is not a relative path, but really part of another path, you would have to scan the whole file system.

Comment: Yeah it has got to do with scanning the filesystem. Any pointers to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

```
new File("\\abc\\xyz").getAbsolutePath();
```

Be aware, though, that this will resolve `.\abc\xyz` from the current working directory. This doesn't include the package path of the class from which you're running this code.

**Update**:

For file-system scans, consider using

```
// Method listing all files matching some filter criteria
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(File directory, 
  IOFileFilter fileFilter, 
  IOFileFilter dirFilter);

// A good filter for your use case
org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter
```

More details:

http://commons.apache.org/io/

Comment: Tried this one. It returns <drivename>:\abc\xyz, unfortunately we need to scan the file system somehow to get the work done.

Comment: As it turns out, System.getenv() helped me to get my work done :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that before, but the only algorithm I can think of is either DFS(depth-first search) or BFS (Breadth-First Search) , where the tree\graph you search on is your file system, where directories are nodes in the graph (it is a tree (acyclic)) and every directories that lead to another have a directed edge (for example abc is a node in the graph that has a directed edge from itself to xyz - another node in the tree).
Once you create your tree data structure, you can perform the BFS or DFS famous algorithms to find the paths.